# List grouped with sublists postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This is a problem I do not how to search and even describe. But I will give it a try.

As a start I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE vch
    (vchid int4, subject text);    
INSERT INTO vch
    (vchid, subject)
VALUES
    (1, 'Volvo'),
    (2, 'Ford'),
    (3, 'Jeep'),
    (4, 'Toyota');

CREATE TABLE rec
    (recid int4, recvch int4, recname text);    
INSERT INTO rec
    (recid, recvch, recname)
VALUES
    (1000, 1,'xxx'),
    (2000, 1,'yyy'),
    (3000, 3,'zzz'),
    (4000, 4,'aaa');
```

The goal i to create an output that looks like this:

```
1 Volvo
{
1000 xxx
2000 yyy
}
3 Jeep
{
3000 zzz 
}
4 Toyota
{
4000 aaa
}
```

It looks related to json, but formatted as above.

The closest i have come is this:

```
SELECT vchid, 0 as id, subject FROM vch
UNION ALL
SELECT recvch, recid, recname FROM rec
ORDER BY 1
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3a61d/12

Comment: Could you be more specific about the desired output? Because the type of `{1000 xxx 2000 yyy}` in the result is not clear. Do you want it as string, or an array of strings, or smth else?

Comment: I have edit my question. Still far from desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

1- Build an string delimited by coma of all records.
2- Creates an array from the string.
3- Finally expand the array using unnest.

```
select unnest(string_to_array(
                  (vchid::text || ' ' || subject
                  || ',{'::text
                  || ',' 
                  || (select string_agg(format(e'%s %s', rec.recid, rec.recname), ',')
                     from rec where vch.vchid = rec.recvch)::text                     
                  || ',}'::text)::text
                  , ','))
from vch;
```

Final result:

```
+----------+
| result   |
+----------+
| 1 Volvo  |
+----------+
| {        |
+----------+
| 1000 xxx |
+----------+
| 2000 yyy |
+----------+
| }        |
+----------+
| 3 Jeep   |
+----------+
| {        |
+----------+
| 3000 zzz |
+----------+
| }        |
+----------+
| 4 Toyota |
+----------+
| {        |
+----------+
| 4000 aaa |
+----------+
| }        |
+----------+
```

This is a set of rows, if you are looking for one text column, @a_horse_with_no_name has supplied the correct answer.

In fact you can get one record by using the provided query by adding a LF to each row.

```
select string_agg(f, chr(10))
from (select unnest(string_to_array(
                  (vchid::text || ' ' || subject
                  || ',{'::text
                  || ',' 
                  || (select string_agg(format(e'%s %s', rec.recid, rec.recname), ',')
                     from rec where vch.vchid = rec.recvch)::text                     
                  || ',}'::text)::text
                  , ',')) f
from vch) a
;
```

This is it:

```
+----------+
| result   |
+----------+
| 1 Volvo  |
| {        |
| 1000 xxx |
| 2000 yyy |
| }        |
| 3 Jeep   |
| {        |
| 3000 zzz |
| }        |
| 4 Toyota |
| {        |
| 4000 aaa |
| }        |
+----------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/JKEG32613

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine embedding newlines in the output, the following would work:

```
with all_rows (id, recid, name, label, src) as (
  SELECT vchid, null as id, subject, concat(vchid, ' ', subject), 1
  FROM vch
  where exists (select 1 from rec where rec.recvch = vch.vchid)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT recvch, recid, recname, concat(recid, ' ', recname), 2
  FROM rec
)    
select case
         when recid is not null and count(*) over (partition by id) <= 2 then concat('{', chr(10), label, chr(10), '}')
         when recid is not null and row_number() over (partition by id order by recid) = 1 then concat('{', chr(10), label)
         when recid is not null 
              and row_number() over (partition by id order by src, recid) = count(*) over (partition by id) then concat(label, chr(10), '}')
         else label
       end as label      
from all_rows
order by id, src, recid nulls first;
```

This outputs:

```
1 Volvo 
{       
1000 xxx
2000 yyy
}
3 Jeep  
{       
3000 zzz
}
4 Toyota
{       
4000 aaa
}
```

However, e.g.

```
{
4000 aaa
}
```

Is a **single row** (and column) but contains embedded newlines.

It depends on how you export that data if that works for you (psql will e.g. display a `+` to indicate line wrapping in the output)

Of course you need to replace the `chr(10)` (newline) with the proper newline character for your platform (e.g. `chr(13), chr(10)` for Windows)

---

Another option is to create a function that does this. Probably a lot easier to handle:

```
create or replace function get_result() 
  returns setof text
as
$$
declare
  v_rec record;
  r_rec record;
begin
  for v_rec in SELECT vchid, subject
               FROM vch
               where exists (select 1 from rec where rec.recvch = vch.vchid)
               order by vchid
  loop
     return next concat(v_rec.vchid, ' ', v_rec.subject);
     return next '{';
     for r_rec in select recid, recname
                  from rec
                  where recvch = v_rec.vchid
                  order by recid
     loop
       return next concat(r_rec.recid, ' ', r_rec.recname);
     end loop;
     return next '}';
  end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then simply run:

```
select *
from get_result();
```

Answer (score 2):

This gives one row result with a text output divided by newline chars:

```
select
    string_agg(
        format(
            e'%s %s\n{\n%s\n}',
            vchid, subject, rec
        ),
        e'\n' order by 1
    ) as result
from (
    select
        vchid,
        subject,
        string_agg(
            format(
                e'%s %s ',
                recid, recname
            ),
            e'\n'
        ) as rec
    from vch
    join rec on vchid = recvch
    group by 1, 2
    ) s;
```

Result:

```
  result   
-----------
 1 Volvo  +
 {        +
 1000 xxx +
 2000 yyy +
 }        +
 3 Jeep   +
 {        +
 3000 zzz +
 }        +
 4 Toyota +
 {        +
 4000 aaa +
 }
(1 row)
```

You can add `unnest(string_to_array())` to the above query to get each line in a single row:

```
select 
    unnest(string_to_array(result, e'\n')) as result
from (  
    select
        string_agg(
            format(
                e'%s %s\n{\n%s\n}',
                vchid, subject, rec
            ),
            e'\n' order by 1
        ) as result
    from (
        select
            vchid,
            subject,
            string_agg(
                format(
                    e'%s %s ',
                    recid, recname
                ),
                e'\n'
            ) as rec
        from vch
        join rec on vchid = recvch
        group by 1, 2
        ) s
    ) s;
```

Result:

```
  result   
-----------
 1 Volvo
 {
 1000 xxx 
 2000 yyy 
 }
 3 Jeep
 {
 3000 zzz 
 }
 4 Toyota
 {
 4000 aaa 
 }
(13 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question what result you expect.
But here is one possible solution that, I guess, results into something similar to what you want.

You could use [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) function and [string concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) to produce an array of strings

```
SELECT vchid, subject, array_agg(rec.recid || ' ' || rec.recname) AS rec
FROM vch JOIN rec ON vch.vchid = rec.recvch
GROUP BY vch.vchid, vch.subject;
```

The result

```
vchid | subject |          rec
------+---------+------------------------
    1 | Volvo   | {"1000 xxx","2000 yyy"}
    3 | Jeep    | {"3000 zzz"}
    4 | Toyota  | {"4000 aaa"}
```

Comment: The intention is to export the figures in a special order without adding an extra layer coding in my application. The data should be "vertical" as showed. Not horizontal. I do not know if this is possible at all.